# Extracting the digit between parentheses in Python

Tags: python, regex

```
import re    
print(re.search('\(\d{1,}\)', "b'   1. Population, 2016 (1)'"))
```

I am trying to extract the digits (one or more) between parentheses in strings. The above codes show my attempted solution. I checked my regular expression on https://regex101.com/ and expected the codes to return True. However, the returned value is None. Can someone let me know what happened?

Comment: [`\(\d+\)`](https://regex101.com/r/gg5mj7/1) that's right, isn't it? or `(?<=\()\d+(?=\))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below RE will help you grab the digits inside the brackets only when the digits are present.

```
r"\((?P<digits_inside_brackets>\d+)\)
```

For your scenario, the above RE will match 1 under the group "digits_inside_brackets".
It can be executed through below snippet

```
import re
user_string = "b'   1. Population, 2016 (1)"
comp = re.compile(r"\((?P<digits_inside_brackets>\d+)\)") # Captures when digits are the only 
for i in re.finditer(comp, user_string):
    print(i.group("digits_inside_brackets"))
```

[Output for the above snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSyMg.png)

Grab digits even when white space are provided:

```
r"\(\s*(?P<digits_inside_brackets>\d+)\s*\)
```

Grab digits inside brackets at any condition:

```
r"\(\D*(?P<digits_inside_brackets>\d+)\D*\)
```

[Output when applied with above RE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsqvA.png)

Answer (score 3):

Your current regex pattern is only valid if you make it a raw string:

```py
inp = "b'   1. Population, 2016 (1)'"
nums = re.findall(r'\((\d{1,})\)', inp)
print(nums)  # ['1']
```

Otherwise, you would have to double escape the `\\d` in the pattern.